# print all arrary values except first value - php

Tags: php

I have an array of numbers. I can print all values using `for each` command in php. But what I want is, I don't want to print first value (ie, `array[0]`) and want to print all other values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $k=>$val){
    if($k){echo $val;}
}
```

for brevity, i did only *exactly* what was asked. The first index has a value of `0` which is falsy, so the value won't get `echo`ed when tested in the `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $cloneArray = $array;
    array_shift($cloneArray); // will remove the first element of array
    foreach($cloneArray as $key => $value){
       echo $key." = ".$value;
    }
```

this will also work if your array is in format of

```
array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2'=> 'value2', ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens..thousands of simple ways to do this.  I'm going to list six:

```
$array = array(5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

foreach ($array as $index => $elem) {
   if ($index == 0) {
      continue;
   }
   echo $elem;
}

foreach($array as $index => $elem) {
   if ($index != 0) {
      echo $elem;
   }
}

for ($x = 1; $x < count($array); $x++) {
   echo $array[$x];
}

$keep = array_shift($array);
foreach ($array as $index => $elem) {
   echo $elem;
}
array_unshift($array, $keep);

foreach (array_diff($array, array($array[0])) as $elem) {
   echo $elem;
}

function print_not_zero($elem, $index) {
   if ($index) {
      echo $elem;
   }
}
array_walk($array, 'print_not_zero');
```

I don't want to insult you, but as a developer you should think more critically for a moment and take the time to visualize the problem.  Otherwise you might waste too much time on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0
foreach($array as $single)
{
  if ($i > 0)
    echo $single;
  $i++;
}
```

Although, unless you're using an associative array, a `for` cycle would be better perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=array(0,1,2,3);
foreach($i as $key=>$value)
{
    if($key!='0')
    echo $value;
}
```