# Fetch mysql results, then randomize order of results, then display one differently from the rest

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have a query that fetches 6 results, then I want to randomize those 6 results so whenever the person reloads the page they will be randomized in order.

Out of those 6 results I want to show one in a separate box than the others, how would I do this?

This is what I was thinking, get results, use shuffle() on the array, then in the separate box I do `echo array[0]['info']`, then the rest I do a `$i = 2; while($i <= 6);` and echo `array[$i]['info'];`

What do you think? is there a better way?

I need this function to be as efficient as possible so any tips are appreciated. Separate queries maybe?

Comment: Yes I fetch the latest 6 results, then I randomize the 6 for display output. This is what I found and feel I"m going to do. Agree with this choice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201967/print-all-arrary-values-except-first-value-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the results in randomized order from MySQL instead of randomizing it in PHP.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6;
```

See also [RAND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) (the notes below)

**Edit:**

To randomize only the last x entries, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6621862/20261) answer.

Comment: I need the latest 6 mysql entries to be randomized, not all of them.

Comment: You can alter the query to fetch only the latest 6

Comment: Limit 6 will take the latest 6 and not randomly from all 5,000 entries? How can I alter the query to do that?

Comment: What do you want, 6 random items, or the last 6 items randomized?

Comment: Last 6 randomized. So I get i get the latest results 6 5 4 3 2 1, THEN them to be randomized to 2 4 3 6 1 5 on every page load. I feel RAND() will make the mysql queries slow so it has to be done in php, just reorganize the array using php somehow.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6621862/20261) answer. That's how it can be done in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this...

```
select * from (select * from table order by date desc limit 6) as t order by rand();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
shuffle( $result );

foreach( $result as $key=>$value ):
    if( $key ):
       // get first item
       $firstOne = $value;
       continue;
    endif;
    // echo others
endforeach;
```

then echo $firstOne in the separate box.